# How to Validate Field in Rails, Active:Model::Validator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to write a validator that will only update the price of a book if the selling status is inactive.

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class BookPriceValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)

    record.errors[:price] << "can't change price on book" if record.selling == "active"
  end
end
```

The problem I'm running into right now is that the error gets called even when the book price is not updated. How can i call this error only when the :price field has actually changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the condition to

```
if record.price_changed? && record.selling == "active"`
```

[ActiveModel::Dirty](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) keeps track of the unpersisted changes made to an `ActiveRecord` object and adds convenience methods for each attribute as `[attribute_name]_changed?`. So all you have to do is check if the price changed along with your current condition.